# Facing issue with identity object after login while using Multiple User Identity Class in Yii2 Advanced

Tags: php, yii2

I have setup/created 2 user identity classes for 2 different login under config/main.php components:

```
'user' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\CustomerUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60*30,
            'loginUrl' => ['customer/login'],
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_panelCustomer',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'franchise'=>[
            'class'=>'yii\web\Franchise',
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\FranchiseUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60*30,
            'loginUrl' => ['franchise/login'],
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_panelFranchise',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

When i logged in using franchise, after login if i check `Yii::$app->user->identity` it gives me details for 1st record in database (vice versa for user login). I want to get null for `Yii::$app->user->identity` when i logged in as franchise.

Comment: I have found the solution for this, please check the answer that i have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we add multiple identity into configuration, please change its `idParam` parameter.

```
'user' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\CustomerUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60*30,
            'loginUrl' => ['customer/login'],
            'idParam' => '__cid',
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_panelCustomer',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
        'franchise' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\User',
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\FranchiseUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60*30,
            'loginUrl' => ['franchise/login'],
            'idParam' => '__fid',
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_panelFranchise',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

You select 1'st components of the user, Check with this:

```
$user = Yii::$app->get('franchise');
$user->identity
```

But, The best solution for this purpose using an advanced template with a separated configuration for users.

```
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced
```

Or you can use module and change configuration in runtime, Inside of Module.php:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    Yii::$app->setComponents([
        'user' => [
            'class'=>'yii\web\Franchise',
            'identityClass' => 'frontend\models\FranchiseUser',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 60*30,
            'loginUrl' => ['franchise/login'],
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_panelFranchise',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

And repeat this for another user module.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i am using yii2 advanced template and under backend i have admin user and under frontend i have 2 users. Issue is with the identity class, when i logged in using franchise its identity class is different (i have created under \yii\web) but it also give me data for user identity class which is different and not logged in.